# MS Visual Studio 2017- Unable to Merge multiple graphs in a single graph

Tags: performance-testing, vsts

It's regarding of load test results analysis- I am unable to merge multiple graphs in a single graph. Ex- By default VSTS has configured a different set of individual graphs like Key Indicators, Controller & Agents and transaction Response times etc.

Here my requirement is like- I have to merge above-mentioned graphs in a single graph. Please help me out on this.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method I know is to pick the graph you want to use and then double-click the indicators you want to see.

If you look below the graphs, you'll note that they list the indicators with a checkbox. Unchecking will remove all the indicators you don't want. You can then use the left menu to choose indicators you want in that specific graph.

[The MSDN library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426918.aspx) has more information - I have used this method to customize what I see on a graph.